# My macro wont run more than once?

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I have a simple macro, since i am very new to it. Literally started today. But i run this macro, and it runs once and stops. Why is that? Here it is:

```
q::
Send asdq
Esc::ExitApp
return
```

If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This is VBA?!?  Is it VBScript, maybe?  I say that because I don't recognize this, and I don't know VBScript...  then again, it might be Mandarin Chinese

Comment: @Hambone this is definetly Mandarin, not VBScript

Comment: Sure this isn't VBA. Is this [AutoHotKey macro](https://autohotkey.com/)? Top result from googling `esc::exitapp`.

Comment: @PatricK Yes, this is AHK. i put VBA by accident

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each hotkey you assign, that isn't a single line, requires a `Return`.

Since you have a definition of a Hotkey inside another, your second hotkey `esc::exitapp` is being executed when you press <kbd>q</kbd> and exiting your script.

Try:

```
q::Send, asdq
Esc::ExitApp
```

or:

```
q::
    Send, asdq
Return

Esc::ExitApp
```

Edit:

```
q::
    Loop 
        Send, asdq
Return

Esc:: ExitApp
```

Comment: I only want it to run when I press Q, not a toggle. Thanks anyways.

Comment: So you want the code to continue to send those characters? What you are looking for is a loop. Added code in a edit.

Comment: So is it clear whether or not the sent q (from sending asdq) is retriggering the sequence?  Maybe try `$q::Send, asdq`

Comment: @PGilm: Good catch, I honestly didn't notice the q in the sequence.