# AHK: {space} not working?

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I have this code that I'm programming for a game I play. Its nothing special. I want it to run a simple function. Sending. Everything works except `{space}`. In the game Spacebar is used to make your character jump. I tried it with that, and it didn't work. Here's the code below:

```
NumpadEnd::
    Send wc
    Sleep, 300
    Send {space}
    Sleep, 600
    Send ddq
    Sleep, 400
    Send e
    Sleep, 500
    Send ssz
    Sleep, 100
    Send g
    Sleep, 1100
    Send asdq
    Sleep, 500
    Send q
    Sleep, 900
    Send sc
    return
```

Comment: Maybe the game measures the duration as well: try `{space down}`, sleep, `{space up}`. Also, try `SendPlay` instead of `Send`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Alright, testing right now.

Comment: @wOxxOm Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Check my response, also the question I answered for you a few days ago still needs to be marked as Answered by YOU. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908584/my-marco-wont-run-more-than-once/39912550#39912550

Comment: @ahkcoder How to?

Comment: @ahkcoder Also, the script didn't work.

Comment: More information would be helpful. What game are attempting this on?

Comment: @ahkcoder ROBLOX.

Comment: Did some research, and it looks like SendInput might work, replace Send with SendInput or try SendMode Input. I edited my script.

Comment: @ahkcoder It kinda of works. Sometimes it works, and some times it doesn't.

Comment: Welp, getting closer, if it's accepting SendInput, likely as @wOxxOm said, it's a matter of dialing timing in. Try his suggestion of {Space Down}, sleep 50, {Space Up} - Edited my code to include an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SendMode Input

NumpadEnd::
    Send wc
    Sleep, 300
    Send {space Down}
    Sleep, 50
    Send {Space up}
    Sleep, 600
    Send ddq
    Sleep, 400
    Send e
    Sleep, 500
    Send ssz
    Sleep, 100
    Send g
    Sleep, 1100
    Send asdq
    Sleep, 500
    Send q
    Sleep, 900
    Send sc
    return
```

Comment: YES!!!! IT WORKS THANK YOU!!!!! I don't know why it didn't work when I tried @wOxxOm's time. I thank both of you.

Comment: No problem, thank you for accepting the answers. Most new users dont take the time.